# Akka.Net shutting down doesn't wait for Serilog?

Tags: f#, serilog, akka.net

I have the following code and I had to add `Threading.Thread.Sleep 5000` to wait for five seconds before shutdown the actor system. Otherwise, some of the Serilog loggings which write to a database will not save. Is there a way to make sure all the logging is done before exit the program?

```
open System
open Akka.FSharp
open Akka

type CRange = CRange of low: string * high: string
type ErrorMessage = string

type CError =
    | LoginFailed of string // Optional reason
    | CTimeOut of CRange list // new range
    | CException of CRange list * exn
    | CMessage of CRange list * ErrorMessage


type CTask = 
    CTask of 
        c: string *
        username: string *
        password: string *
        proxyAddress: string *
        cycle: DateTime *
        issuerRange: CRange list *
        filterTable: bool

type DoWork = Map<string, CTask -> Result<int * string, CError>>

type PartKeyCount = PartKeyCount of Key: string * Count: int
type PartGroupCount = PartGroupCount of Group: string list * Count: int

let system = System.create "ASystem" <| Configuration.load ()

let scheduler (actors: Actor.IActorRef list) task (mailbox: Actor<Result<int, CError>>) =
    let newTask task range =
        let (CTask(c, username, password, proxy, cycle, _, filter)) = task
        CTask(c, username, password, proxy, cycle, range, filter)
    let rec loop (list: CRange list list) running = actor {
        let akkaName = mailbox.Self.Path.Name
        printfn "%s scheduler loop (Running: %d Todo:%d)" akkaName running list.Length
        let! m = mailbox.Receive ()
        let sender = mailbox.Sender ()
        printfn "%s received message %A from %A" akkaName m sender
        match m with
        | Ok _ ->
            printfn "finished one"
            match list with
            | [] ->
                if running = 1 then
                    //Log.Information("....")
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep 5000 // Wait for 5 seconds
                    mailbox.Context.System.Terminate() |> ignore
                else    
                    return! loop [] (running - 1)
            | x :: xs ->
                printfn "Finished one. Todo %d, running %d - %A. New task %A to %A" xs.Length running sender x sender
                let t = newTask task x
                sender.Tell(t, mailbox.Self) // <! 
                return! loop xs running
        | _ -> ()
    }
    let groups = [(CRange ("A","A"), 1); (CRange ("B","B"), 1); (CRange ("C","C"), 1);
        (CRange ("D","D"), 1); (CRange ("zzz","zzz"), 1)]
    let n = if actors.Length < groups.Length then actors.Length else groups.Length
    [0..n-1] |> List.iter(fun i -> 
        let t = newTask task [fst groups.[i]]
        actors.[i].Tell(t, mailbox.Self))
    let todo = groups |> Seq.skip n |> Seq.toList |> List.map(fun (x, _) -> [x])
    Console.WriteLine("Groups {0}; Running {1}; Todo: {2}", groups.Length, n, todo.Length)
    loop todo n

let processor (mailbox: Actor<CTask>) =
    let rec loop () = actor {
        let! m = mailbox.Receive ()
        let sender = mailbox.Sender ()
        let akkaName = mailbox.Self.Path.Name
        printfn "* %s received message %A from %A" akkaName m sender
        sender <! (Ok DateTime.Now.Millisecond :> Result<int, CError>)
        printfn "* %s sent to %A." akkaName sender
        return! loop()
    }
    loop ()

let spawnSystems n = 
    [1..n] 
    |> List.map(fun i ->
        spawn system (sprintf "Processor%d" i) (processor)    
    )

let startAkka task actorNumber =
    let actors = spawnSystems actorNumber
    Threading.Thread.Sleep 1000
    scheduler actors task  
    |> spawn system "Scheduler"
    |> ignore
    system.WhenTerminated.Wait()

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let c = "priv"
    let cycle = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1)
    let username, password = "username", "password"
    let task = CTask(c, username, password, "", cycle, [], false)
    startAkka task 2 
    0
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible. By default logging is designed to work in non-blocking fashion, so that writing log statement will not cripple important parts of your application.

Comment: Not an answer, an idea, if you get hold of Logger you can CloseAndFlush()?

Answer (score 1):

Before shutting down the Akka.net actor system, you need to tell Serilog to "flush" any buffered messages. There are different ways of doing that depending on how you're using Serilog.

The easiest way to use Serilog is via the global `Log` class:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File(@"myapp\log.txt")
    .CreateLogger();

Log.Information("Hello!");

// Your application runs, then:

Log.CloseAndFlush();
```

If don't use the static `Log` class, you will use `LoggerConfiguration` to create an `ILogger` and dispose that instance.

```
using (var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.File(@"myapp\log.txt")
        .CreateLogger())
{
    log.Information("Hello again!");

    // Your app runs, then disposal of `log` flushes any buffers
}
```

> You can see more details on the **[Lifecycle of Loggers](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Lifecycle-of-Loggers)**.